# Restrict people by using PHP GET Variable

Tags: php, get

In one of the interview question i get below question

> "How you can restrict your developers in your custom build framework
>   to use `$_GET` variable."

We have our own custom build framework but in our framework we can not restrict people to use `$_GET` or `$_POST` in place of `$this->request->get` or `$this->request->post`.

We have method for accessing this variable but people most of the time uses `$_GET` or `$_POST` instead of our methods.

Can you please give me answer for that?

Thanks

Comment: Create a repository *reject* for code that contains $_GET/$_POST and instruct the offending party what techniques to use :) (Alternatively, don't reject, but blame/code-review: same idea though - detect and correct.)

Comment: No matter what solution you adopt, a developer would always be able to `parse_str(getenv('QUERY_STRING'), $_GET=array())` to circumvent it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In php.ini, remove the `G` and `P` characters from the `variables_order` option.

Alternatively, if you want them to hate you forever, you could copy the contents of the superglobal, then set it to an instance of a class that throws an exception whenever you try to interact with it:

```
class supaglobal implements arrayaccess
{
    public function _construct(){}

    function offsetExists($offset) {
        throw new Exception("Don't use GET, bro");
    }
    function offsetSet($property, $value){
        throw new Exception("Don't use GET, bro");
    }
    function offsetUnset($property) {
        throw new Exception("Don't use GET, bro");
    }
    function offsetGet($property){
        throw new Exception("Don't use GET, bro");
    }
}

$approvedget = $_GET;
$_GET = new supaglobal();
$abcd = $_GET["abcd"]; // throws exception
$abcd = $approvedget["abcd"]; // A - OK
```

Comment: Mentioned `$this->request->get` and `$this->request->post` probably use `$_POST` and `$_GET`. So by removing `G` and `P` those properties will return `null`.